# Symfony2 callback validation on trait

Tags: php, validation, symfony, traits

I want to use callback validation on a trait. For example:

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateReview"}, groups={"review"})
 */
trait ReviewableEntity
{
    //...

    /**
     * @param ExecutionContext $context
     */
    public function validateReview(ExecutionContext $context)
    {

        //...

        $context->addViolationAt('review', 'Review must be valid', [], null);

        //...

    }

    //...

}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know if this is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the annotation is on the trait (and not on the method, which is possible with Symfony `2.4+`), the callback validator cannot be used with annotations in a trait.

You must use this method if your version of Symfony2 is older than `2.4`:

```
namespace Vendor\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

trait ReviewableEntity
{
    //...

    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addConstraint(
            new Assert\Callback(
                'validateReview',
                array(
                    'groups' => array('review'),
                )
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param ExecutionContext $context
     */
    public function validateReview(ExecutionContext $context)
    {

        //...

        $context->addViolationAt('review', 'Review must be valid', [], null);

        //...

    }

    //...

}
```

This is just the normal php way to deal with validators without using annotations or configuration file in XML or YML.

I've found this answer with this google query "`github symfony entity trait assert callback`" as I was fighting with the same problem. For me the first result was [this gihtub page containing code that solve the problem](https://github.com/Victoire/victoire/blob/master/Bundle/WidgetBundle/Entity/Traits/LinkTrait.php).

Comment: So what is the correct (simplest) method for Symfony 2.4+?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. Found this one via google ... So: I reproduced the problem. Same here.

Extra bit of information: If you put an @Assert annotation on a property inside the trait, it will work. Just the callbacks do not work.